# Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'?

Tags: android, json

I have created my own `JSON` file but I am getting following error 
Error: Parse error on line 4:
        ...nical University"        'Freelance Android D
        ----------------------^
        Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

**below my `json` structure where I have created my own `json` api**

```
{
        "Introduction": [{
            "image": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lxgp2xj8wtv3zk/10762650.jpg?dl=0qaC8sFGR/tA4zUizSJLwx+oamRxyLDuPAPc/4Un7thhg2evDYq0Sf/9k=FLMf",
            "introduction": "My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated  Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University"
            'Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient.'
            'Developed more than 10 android apps'

        }],
        "Education": [{
            "duration": "2012-2014",
            "institution": "Riga Technical University Latvia, Riga",
            "degree": "Bachelor Degree in Computer Science"
        }],
        "Work": [{
                "company": "Udacity",
                "duration": " Jun 2018 - Present ",
                "responsibility": "Android Project Reviewer"
            },
            {
                "company": "Mobi Verse",
                "duration": " Jan 2018 - Present",
                "responsibility": "Developing Android apps for US market"
            },
            {
                "company": "Freelancer",
                "duration": " Jan 2017 - Present",
                "responsibility": "Developing  eCommerce  and different various android apps"
            },
            {
                "company": "Softwerk AB",
                "duration": " December 2016 - May 2017",
                "responsibility": " Maintaining existing Android apps"
            }
        ],
        "Skills": [{
            "Programming": "Java, C Sharp, Kotlin, Swift",
            "Framework/Libraries": "Android, IOS",
            "Android Architecture Components": "Live Data, ViewModel, Room",
            "Software Methodologies": "Agile, Scrum, Waterfall",
            "IDE'S": "Eclipse, Android Studio, Xcode"
        }],
        "Contact": [{
            "Linkedin": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/edgar-sweden/",
            "gmail": "kyodgorbek@gmail.com",
            "phone number": "+46760981871"
        }]
}
```

Comment: your JSON is not valid. You need to escape your quotes. Use `\"` instead of `"` inside your values

Comment: mojej napisat primer

Comment: I have done but it is stil giving an error

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it is still giving an error

Comment: which one? What you changed?

Comment: "introduction": /"My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University 
  'Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient.'
  'Developed more than 10 android apps'" Error: Parse error on line 4:
...,  "introduction": /"My name is Yodgorb
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can you see that

Comment: can you write sample for me please

Comment: You need to change the `"introduction"` value to a double quoted string (without single quote) and possibly use `\n` if you need line break. The result should be like `"introduction": "...\n...\n..."`

Comment: Ok, you did wrong. JSON key-value pairs should be like `"key":"vlaue"`. And if you have double quotes inside the value, you have to escape them. like if your value is `my "value"`, then you key-value pair should look like `"key":"my \"value\""`

Comment: @oliv can you write full sample for me I am stuck "introduction": "My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University 
  '/n Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient.'
  '/n Developed more than 10 android apps"

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, can you write for me full sample please

Comment: "introduction": /"/My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University 
  ' Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient.'
  ' Developed more than 10 android apps/"/ like this one

Comment: @Vladislav guys can you write full sample in the code I am stuck please everybody giving suggestion

Comment: by `full sample` you mean `do it instead of you`?

Answer (score 0):

```
"introduction": “My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient. Developed more than 10 android apps”
}]
```

Because you closed your double quotes after *University*, the value for the key *introduction* ended there. If everything after that is another info, you need to have a new key for that.

Comment: I am getting an error please help me to correct it please again please

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data has errors. If you need to have a multi-line string, use `\n`. So you need to set the `introduction` field like this:

```
"introduction": "My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated  Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University\nFreelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient.\nDeveloped more than 10 android apps"
```

Not that I don't think you need single quote `'` in that text.

Answer (score 0):

you have closed your string that should be continuous. you can use below json.

```
{
    "Introduction": [{
        "image": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lxgp2xj8wtv3zk/10762650.jpg?dl=0qaC8sFGR/tA4zUizSJLwx+oamRxyLDuPAPc/4Un7thhg2evDYq0Sf/9k=FLMf",
        "introduction": "My name is Yodgorbek Komilov I have graduated  Bachelor of Computer Science at Riga Technical University Freelance Android Developer who loves to create Android apps and Google Android Developer scholarship recipient. Developed more than 10 android apps."
    }],
    "Education":// your other code as it is
}
```

always validate json if you are not sure there are plenty of [online services](https://jsonlint.com/) for it.